# Cutting a stick into 3 pieces; what is the expected middle length?

Tags: probability, expected-value, order-statistics

The problem is

> Given a stick of length $L$. You randomly cut it in 2 locations to get 3 sub-sticks. What is the expected length of the shortest, longest, and middle length stick? Note that "middle" here does not mean the segment in the middle of the stick after you cut it at 2 locations. It is referring to the second largest (or equivalent, second smallest) of the 3 segments.
> So for example, if after cutting and we have that the lengths are $x, y-x, 1-y$, the longest length is $\max(x, y-x, 1-y)$, the shortest is $\min(y, y-x, 1-y)$ and the remaining is the "middle" length.

I've solved the problem for the expected length of the shortest and longest length. And it's pretty obvious that the expectation of the shortest, longest and middle length stick is equal to $L$, so I could compute the expected middle length very easily give expected longest and shortest length.

However, if I didn't already solve for the expected longest and shortest length, and instead want to directly solve for the expected middle length, how would one do that? The first and last order statistic are pretty easy to compute, but the middle one seems it would be rather tedious?

Answer (score 3):

Cutting in two random places of a length $L$ stick corresponds to picking a random point in an $L\times L$ square. You can divide this square into regions depending on whether it is the left, right or middle piece that has middle length. Define a function from the square to the real numbers as the length of the middle length segment.

Integrate this function over the square, divide by $L^2$, and you're done. The integral on each region of the square should be rather easy.

Comment: Does the x and y coordinates of a point in the square represent the locations at which you make a cut?

Comment: @student010101 Yes. You can just use a triangle rather than the whole square, if the $x$ coordinate is the left cut and the $y$ coordinate is the right cut, or you can have "first and second" cuts, and use a square.

Comment: I'm still kind of confused how this helps me find the expected middle length. So far I understand that I have a triangle with the bounds $x \geq 0, y \geq 0, x+y < L$, and if choose a random point inside this triangle then the x and y coordinates of this point represents the location of the first and second cuts. Let's suppose the point is at (a,b). Then we know that the lengths are $\min(a,b), 1-\max(a,b), |b-a|$. But how does the graphical approach us determine the expected middle length?

Comment: @student010101 No, not $x+y<L$. I mean $x,y<L$. The two coordinates are the position of the two cuts relative to the entire rod. The second cut isn't measured from the first, but rather the are both measured from the same end of the original rod. But still. You have your three functions. It is an elementary matter to decide which of them is the middle value on any given point in the square. This divides the square up into regions. For each region, one of your three functions is the middle length. The regions are simple, and on each region the relevant function is simple. Just integrate.

Comment: In general (as long as things are nice enough), if we pick a point $x$ uniformly at random on a region, the expected value of $f(x)$ is the integral of $f$ over the region, divided by the integral of $1$ over the region.

Comment: Ahhhh I just realized that I wasn't clear what "middle" means. Middle length here isn't actually the segment in the middle of the stick after cutting. The middle length here is the the second longest or second shortest length of the 3 segments.

Comment: @student010101 Yes, that does make communication a bit difficult. I did try to be somewhat clear in my above comment about the distinction between the two meanings of "middle", although that may have failed (I used both, at different times, not the best idea ever). But I did already know that you meant the one that was neither shortest nor longest, rather than neither leftest nor rightest.

Comment: Are the said regions obvious to distinguish? I'm essentially fixing an $X$ value and varying $Y$ and seeing what the middle length would be, but I seem to be having a hard time generalizing this. If we let $S, M, L$ denote the smallest, middle and longest length pieces, and that $X < Y$, then we have that $S = \min(X, Y-X, 1-Y), L = \max(X, Y-X, 1-Y)$.